# How to get single parameter from JSON response in JMeter and use in other HTTP request?

Tags: testing, automation, jmeter, automated-tests

I want to fetch one parameter from JSON response in the JMeter tool.

Currently, I am calling one API through JMeter and in response I got various parameter in jason format, but I want to fetch single parameter from that request and want to call another API Using that Parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Use [extractors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to parse response and get any data from it. E.g. if your JSON response looks like this:

```
{
  "TITLE": "Empire Burlesque",
  "ARTIST": "Bob Dylan",
  "COUNTRY": "USA",
  "COMPANY": "Columbia",
  "PRICE": "10.90",
  "YEAR": "1985"
}
```

You can use this options:

1. [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=JSONPathExtractor) 
   [image: JSON Path Extractor]
2. [JSON extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
   [image: JSON extractor]
3. [Regex extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
   [image: Regexr extractor]
4. [SmartMeter](https://www.smartmeter.io)'s [Boundary Body extractor](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-et-sm---boundary-body-extractor) - fastest solution, but you need SmartMeter
   [image: Boundary body]

Of course you can use Beanshell, JSR22 or jQuery extractors.

After extracting data to variable `my_title` you can use this variable in another requests like this `${my_title}`

Comment: Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Since JMeter 3.0 there is [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which can execute arbitrary [JSON Path queries](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) against responses, this way you will be able to extract the data you require and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for later re-use.

See [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) guide for comprehensive information and real-life use-case.